# Curl has https support but when used it claims that it is not supported

Tags: curl, https

I am trying to get stormpath working with curl.

```
curl -X POST --user $YOUR_API_KEY_ID:$YOUR_API_KEY_SECRET \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
       "givenName": "Jean-Luc",
       "surname": "Picard",
       "username": "jlpicard",
       "email": "capt@enterprise.com",
       "password":"Changeme1"
    }' \      "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/$YOUR_APPLICATION_ID/accounts"
```

When I try this I get the message:

```
curl: (1) Protocol  https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

To see what curl supports I ran curl -V:

```
curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) libcurl/7.30.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

As you can see https is a supported protocol.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  On the last line I have a backslash that was for line continuation and I continued on the same line:

```
}' \      "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/$YOUR_APPLICATION_ID/accounts"
```

Once I took the backslash out it worked! :)

```
}'  "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/$YOUR_APPLICATION_ID/accounts"
```

Hope that helps someone.

Andrew